# save file with dynamic name adobe flex air

Tags: apache-flex, air, adobe

I am trying to save jpg files to my applicationStorageDirectory with custom names.

```
var filename:String = "visitorimage.jpg";

        var file:File = File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath( filename );
        var wr:File = new File( file.nativePath );
        var stream:FileStream = new FileStream();
        stream.open( wr , FileMode.WRITE);
        stream.writeBytes ( imageData, 0,imageData.length );
        stream.close();
```

The image is saved but i need to give the image dynamic name say using a timestamp or random number.Please help and thanks in advance.

Comment: You could use, say... a timestamp or a random number, couldn't you ?

Comment: Are you asking how to generate a random number or how to get a timestamp? If you're asking such trivial questions then the code you just copied is not your own.

Comment: Hi Rob, I am a web developer from PHP, javascript background. Just started a desktop visitor app in flex and started studying it using flashdevelop. I am only a newbie here .. Please try to understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Date](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Date.html?filter_flash=cs5&filter_flashplayer=10.2&filter_air=2.6) class is useful for getting a timestamp. I wouldn't recommend using a random number as it is not repeat safe.

Answer (score 0):

Create a seperate method that generates a random number, within this method concatinate visitorimage.jpg to the random number and return it as a string.

Sorted :)